# Delete all lines between two patterns (exclusive of the pattern) using sed or awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a somewhat large output text file where I need to delete all lines between two patterns but retain the pattern match.

The files look vaguely like the following output.

```
 TEST #1          
      coef1 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
      coef2 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
            |
  indicator |
         0  |   .6647992   2.646627     0.25   0.802     -4.55925    5.888849
         1  |   2.118701   5.225777     0.41   0.686     -8.19621    12.43361
            |
       year |
         2  |  -.4324005   2.231387    -0.19   0.847    -4.836829    3.972028
         3  |   -.362762    1.97184    -0.18   0.854    -4.254882    3.529358
            |
      _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
 TEST #2          
        coef2 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
        coef3 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
              |
         year |
           4  |   .6647992   2.646627     0.25   0.802     -4.55925    5.888849
           5  |   2.118701   5.225777     0.41   0.686     -8.19621    12.43361
              |
     idnumber |
           6  |  -.4324005   2.231387    -0.19   0.847    -4.836829    3.972028
           7  |   -.362762    1.97184    -0.18   0.854    -4.254882    3.529358
              |
        _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
```

I need to take the following output and delete all the lines between "year" and "_cons" but I need to retain the line starting with "_cons".  The desired output is like so:

```
 TEST #1          
      coef1 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
      coef2 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
            |
  indicator |
         0  |   .6647992   2.646627     0.25   0.802     -4.55925    5.888849
         1  |   2.118701   5.225777     0.41   0.686     -8.19621    12.43361
            |
       year |
      _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
 TEST #2          
        coef2 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
        coef3 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
              |
         year |
        _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
```

I wrote the following script (under OS X):

```
sed '/^ +year/,/^ +_cons/{/^ +year/!{/^ +_cons/!d}}' input.txt >output.txt
```

but I got the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/^ +year/,/^ +_cons/{/^ ...": extra characters at the end of d command
```

I'm not sure if this approach is even correct because I can't seem to get sed to execute.  Is sed even appropriate here or should I use awk?

One last note, I need this script to work on a relatively generic Unix install.  I have to send this to someone who must execute it under a very basic AIX (I think) install.  No perl, no python, and I can't do much troubleshooting on their install over email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a semicolon after `d` to indicate that the command has ended. (GNU `sed` — the only `sed` I have handy to test with — doesn't require this, but maybe another `sed` would?)

Also, if you need to support multiple implementations of `sed`, then you can't use `+` to mean "one or more": it's not standard, and not all implementations support it. You can use `\{1,\}`, but that's pretty ugly . . . I'd just use `*` and tack on an extra copy.

So:

```
sed '/^ * year/,/^ * _cons/{/^ * year/!{/^ * _cons/!d;}}' input.txt >output.txt
```

(Tested, but only using GNU `sed`, not OS X, and certainly not AIX, sorry.)

Comment: Won't this remove `year` line as well?

Comment: @JaypalSingh: No . . . well, yes, but not for any deep reason: it's only that I failed to replace one instance of `+` with `*`. Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This should work -

```
awk '/year/{print; getline; while($0!~/_cons/) {getline}}1' INPUT_FILE
```

**or**

```
awk '/_cons/{print;f=0;next}/year/{f=1;print;next}f{next}1' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Following is the Output with your input-data file:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/year/{print; getline; while($0!~/_cons/) {getline}}1' file
TEST #1          
      coef1 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
      coef2 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
            |
  indicator |
         0  |   .6647992   2.646627     0.25   0.802     -4.55925    5.888849
         1  |   2.118701   5.225777     0.41   0.686     -8.19621    12.43361
            |
       year |
      _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
 TEST #2          
        coef2 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
        coef3 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
              |
         year |
        _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
```

#### Test2:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/_cons/{print;f=0;next}/year/{f=1;print;next}f{next}1' file
TEST #1          
      coef1 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
      coef2 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
            |
  indicator |
         0  |   .6647992   2.646627     0.25   0.802     -4.55925    5.888849
         1  |   2.118701   5.225777     0.41   0.686     -8.19621    12.43361
            |
       year |
      _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
TEST #2          
      coef2 |   48.36895    3.32013    14.57   0.000     41.86141    54.87649
      coef3 |  -50.08894   10.47335    -4.78   0.000    -70.61697   -29.56092
            |
       year |
      _cons |   16.95753   6.342342     2.67   0.008     4.526383    29.38869
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/year/,/_cons/{//!d}' file
```

or:

```
 awk '/_cons/{p=0};!p;/year/{p=1}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it visually.
Just open the file with **`gVim`**, and run the command:

```
:g/^\s*year/+1,/^\s*_cons/-1 d
```

#### Explanation:

- **`g`** global command
- **`/^\s*year/+1`** match line bellow `year`
- **`/^\s*_cons/-1`** match line above `_cons`
- **`d`** delete the range

Answer (score 0):

To summarize and generalize the two GNU sed solutions that work:

```
sed '/BEGIN/,/END/{/BEGIN/!{/END/!d;}}' input.txt
sed '/BEGIN/,/END/{//!d}' input.txt
```